# interactive 3D content - which format supports?

Tags: pdf, creation

I am looking for options to display a 3D rendered model with some interactivity.
Adobe does (used to ?) support for 3D content, however as I know it doesn't work on handhold devices or mobiles, only on desktop.

Is there any format (pdb, epub, mobi etc) that is supporting 3D content on handheld devices and if there is any reasonable way to generate the 3D content (visuals on molecules, i.e. bunch of balls and tubes and surfaces)?

Comment: For PDF, the situation is really bleak; even the leader of the pack (PDF Expert by Readdle) does not support any 3D functions.

Comment: Frankly, I am not sure about Adobe-s support neither. Many of the 3D tools are not available or not documented in recent Adobe packages.

Comment: Are you now talking about Acrobat for Windows/Mac, or Reader for mobile? In the first case, the display tools are around, but you'd have to acquire the development tools separately.

Comment: @MaxWyss Ideally, I would prefer mobile / ipad / tablet solutions. Also, it was not clear for me what are the recent development tools in the Creative Cloud package (all descriptions are older and refer to either CAD or discontinued Adobe products for creation) .